# Return to root view controller (storyboard)

Tags: storyboard, root, viewcontroller

My app works with storyboards. When the app launches, it loads ViewController1 (with the arrow thing in storyboards). After logging in it pops to a navigation controller.
However, I have this button in here which should bring me back to the initial view controller from the storyboard. How should I do this?
This doesn't work:

```
[(UINavigationController *)self.view popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];